# “Fuir” or “s'enfuir”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What is the best word for, "to flee", as "in he fled" or "we should flee", or perhaps just "We should get out of here!". 
In the dictionary I find two verbs fuir and s'enfuir. What's the difference?
(I realize that this may have been discussed before, but alas at a level beyond my comprehension, at least in French.

and because I am so happy with the excellent answers I receive here, I leave you with an amusing poem. If you are a teacher, your students may also enjoy it, as an example of the chaos of English. Thank you all!

> A flea and a fly in a flu,
>   Were imprisoned, so what could they do.
>   Said the flea, 'Let us fly."
>   Said the fly, "Let us flee."
>   So they flew through a flaw in the flu.

Comment: They are very similar. I would say "fuir" is with your mind, and "s'enfuir" is with your legs, but kinda hard to say...

Comment: fuir: transitif : vis à vis de quelque chose, un endroit, une personne, un état. En général avec COD (mais on peut aussi l'omettre). S'enfuir: pronominal, qui peuvent s'employer sans complément: déplacement physique.

Comment: it's a flue that they are caught in, no?

Comment: Yes, a flue. Sorry, I am a terrible speller, and english is a terrible language for anyone who has difficulty with spelling.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "best word". Good translations depend on the context.

Possible ones for "he fled" might be:

> *Il s'est échappé (de sa cellule, de son enclos)*
>
> *Il s'est évadé (de prison)*
>
> *Il a fui (ses responsabilités, son pays, sa famille, à l'étranger,...)*
>
> *Il s'est enfui (de chez lui, de son pays, à l'étranger,...)*
>
> *Il a quitté (son pays/sa femme/...)*

Comment: Pour « quitter », j'utiliserais « _to leave_ ». Pour « échapper » et « évader », je préfèrerais « _to escape_ ». D'accord avec la réponse nonobstant.

Comment: @Chop Je pensais à *he fled his wife* que je ne traduirais probablement pas par *Il a fui sa femme* mais par *il a quitté sa femme*.

Comment: Certes, mais on véhicule dans ce cas un peu plus que la simple dimension « administrative ». Il y a une notion de désertion, d'abandon à faire passer. « Abandonné » ?

Comment: "Il s'est sauvé."

Answer (score 4):

They are quite similar in meaning with a difference of emphasis,

- *fuir* put the emphasis on what is fled from (even if it is implied).
- *s'enfuir* put the emphasis on the movement itself.

And to complete with the other verbs cited by @jlliagre:

- *s'échapper* implies that there was a constraint.
- *s'évader* implies a stronger constraint, probably legal, the most common usage is for convicts and prisonners.